# Retrieve values from array within df based on lengt function

Tags: python, pandas

How do you retrieve the first n values from an array within the a dataframe,

where n is the length of that same array - 1: (len[array] - 1)?

To clarify what I am aiming for here is the code I have so far, from my jupyter notebook:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#load csv into pandas data frame
df1 = pd.read_csv(r"accounts.csv")
#define the range for clarity
xi = 60
xn = 70
df1['splt_acc'] = df1.Account.str.split('.')
df1['len'] = df1.splt_acc.apply(lambda x: len(x)-1).astype(int)
df1['parent'] = df1.splt_acc.str.join('.')
pd.DataFrame(df1)[xi:xn]
```

shows the following

```
    Account Rubriek       splt_acc  len parent
60  9.5     Inkoop        [9, 5]    1   9.5
61  9.6     Overige res.. [9, 6]    1   9.6
62  9.7     Buitengewon.. [9, 7]    1   9.7
63  9.8     Incidentele.. [9, 8]    1   9.8
64  9.9     Vennootschap. [9, 9]    1   9.9
65  0.0.0   Terreinen     [0, 0, 0] 2   0.0.0
66  0.0.1   Gebouwen      [0, 0, 1] 2   0.0.1
67  0.0.2   Verbouwingen  [0, 0, 2] 2   0.0.2
68  0.0.3   Machines      [0, 0, 3] 2   0.0.3
69  0.0.4   Gereedschappen[0, 0, 4] 2   0.0.4
```

and the next thing I want is:

```
df1['y'] = df1.splt_acc.apply(lambda splt_acc: splt_acc[0:df1.len])
pd.DataFrame(df1)[xi:xn]
```

This results in the following error: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

With a simpler method I can get the result per row, in this case row 60:

```
account = df1['Account'][60]
x = account.split('.')

if len(x) - 1 == 0:
    y = 'null'
else:
    y = x[0:(len(x)-1)]

print(y)
```

['9']

```
if y == 'null':
    parent = 'null'
else:
    parent = ".".join(str(x) for x in y)

print(parent)
```

9

But the question is, how can I get the same result within my DataFrame?

Comment: first n values where n is always the length of the array? i.e, all values but the last one?

Comment: correct! I want to retrieve all values except the last value of that array. The goal is to create a parent account based on the account value. So in row 68 account = 0.0.4 and parent should be 0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Account': ['9', '9.5', '9.6', '9.7', '9.8', '9.9', '0.0.0', '0.0.1', '0.0.2', '0.0.3', '0.0.4']})

df1.assign(
    parent=df1['Account'].str.split('.').apply(lambda x: '.'.join(x[:-1]) or 'null'))
>>> df1
   Account parent
0        9   null
1      9.5      9
2      9.6      9
3      9.7      9
4      9.8      9
5      9.9      9
6    0.0.0    0.0
7    0.0.1    0.0
8    0.0.2    0.0
9    0.0.3    0.0
10   0.0.4    0.0
```

Comment: This is perfectly compact! thanks! There was a ) missing btw

Comment: Thanks.  I've added the extra closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is,

```
df1['y'] = df1.splt_acc.apply(lambda x: x[:-1])
```

What this means is you are taking all the values from 0 till the 2nd last value.
For example,

```
a = [5,3,6,4]
```

then, `a[:-1] returns [5,3,6]`

Moreover, you can do this in the start itself,

```
df1['y'] = df1.Account.str.split('.')[:-1]
```